# How is it possible to change keyboard layout when its default layout is not English?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, default, xkb

I've mistakenly changed the default keyboard layout in `/etc/default/keyboard` to `persian`. Also input source switching shortcuts are disabled and there is no options in `/etc/default/keyboard` for switching layouts.

Now I cannot login to the system because my password is in English and the default  layout is in Persian. Even when I switch to command line (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), I cannot do anything (I can just type Persian characters).

Even in recovery mode (grub option) the keyboard is in Persian.

So what is the solution? how can I switch to english layout?

Comment: If the machine is local; I'd boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), `mount` your partition and make the change that way. I have no experience with language/layouts thus my (*quick/dirty*) raw fix approach.

Comment: Currently I don't have access to  ubuntu install media, and I'm wondering is there other options in this situation?

Comment: `ssh` in; the keyboard will be controlled by the machine you're typing into which won't be Persian. *You'll have to have openssh-server installed & running; your `xkb` reference implies to me it was a desktop not a server*

Comment: @guiverc Unfortunately ssh is disabled in that system, anyway I've solved the problem by live os solution.